# Using libraries made for amd64 on arm64

Tags: emulation, cpu-architecture

For a class, we have to use a c library that was only ever compiled for amd64, and is now so old some of its dependencies don’t even exist anymore (aka impossible to recompile)

Is there a way to build and run a project using this library through an emulator, without having to emulate the entire OS along with it ? The only computer I have is an M1 MacBook Air, which has an arm64 processor.

The library in question is [MLV](http://www-igm.univ-mlv.fr/%7Eboussica/mlv/api/French/html/index.html)

Comment: M1 Macs have Rosetta for running amd64 binaries. Are you running an Ubuntu VM?

Comment: You *may* be able to do this via Docker, as that layer will work with Rosetta to a point. Be sure to have all of the Xcode tools installed beforehand, though.

Comment: QEMU works on many ARM hosts, and can create amd64 VM guests.

Comment: Multipass runs on M1. https://multipass.run/docs/installing-on-macos